# Как вывести ключ и значение TreeMap

Tags: java

Если пишем новое имя, программа просит ввести номер телефона и запоминает его. Если новый номер телефона — просит ввести имя и также запоминает.
Если вводим существующее имя или номер телефона, программа выводит всю информацию о контакте.
При вводе команды LIST программа печатает в консоль список всех абонентов в алфавитном порядке с номерами.
При итерации TreeMap и выводе содержимого значение выводился как null:

```
LIST
79027555543null
79037555587null
79076555543null
Аннаnull
Василийnull
Федорnull
```

Что нужно исправить, чтобы map выводилось в таком виде?

-79037555587 Федор
-79016555576 Анна
-79027666687 Иван

Мой код:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Введите данные: ");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        TreeMap<String, String> map = new TreeMap<>();

        while (true) {
            String str = scanner.next();
            Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("[a-zA-Zа-яА-Я.].").matcher(str);
            Matcher matcher2 = Pattern.compile("^7\\d{10}$").matcher(str);
            if (str.equals("LIST")) {
                for (Map.Entry<String, String> item2 : map.entrySet()) {
               System.out.println(item2.getKey()+item2.getValue());
                }
            } else if (matcher2.find()) {
                if (map.containsKey(str)) {

                    System.out.println(map.get(str));
                } else {
                    System.out.println(" Введите имя :");
                    map.put(str, map.get(str));
                }
            } else if (matcher.find()) {
                if (map.containsValue(str)) {
                    for (Map.Entry<String, String> item : map.entrySet()) {
                        if (str.equals(item.getValue())) {

                            System.out.println(item.getKey());
                        }
                    }
                } else System.out.println(" Введите телефон :");
                map.put(str, map.get(str));

            } else System.out.println("Введите верное значение");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что после запросов `Введите имя` и `Введите телефон`, из `System.in` ничего не читается, а вместо этого делается:

```
map.put(str, map.get(str));
```

где `str` это значение, которое пользователь уже ввел и которое проверялось. Оно используется как ключ и в словарь вставляется всегда `null`.

Нужно добавить после запроса имени что-то вроде:

```
System.out.println(" Введите имя :");
String name = scanner.next();
map.put(str, name);
```

А после ввода телефона:

```
else {
   System.out.println(" Введите телефон :");
   String phone = scanner.next();
   map.put(phone, str);
}
```